# Laravel Stripe checkout: 419 (unknown status)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, stripe-payments

I am trying to use Stripe checkout using the payment page hosted on Stripe. Stripe documentation works with pure PHP. But with Laravel, its not redirecting to Stripe payment page. In the console, it shows `POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/stripe 419 (unknown status)` and `Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`. According to some posts, I added `https://checkout.stripe.com/` in the *VerifyCsrfToken* middleware.

The checkout page:

```
<head>
    ...
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?version=3.52.1&features=fetch"></script>
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" id="checkout-button">Checkout</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var stripe = Stripe("{{ env('STRIPE_KEY') }}");;
    var checkoutButton = document.getElementById("checkout-button");
    checkoutButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        fetch("{{ route('stripe-store') }}", {
            method: "POST",
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function (session) {
                return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
            })
            .then(function (result) {
                if (result.error) {
                    alert(result.error.message);
                }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.error("Error:", error);
            });
    });
</script>
```

In controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $checkout_session = Session::create([
        'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
        'line_items' => [[
            'price_data' => [
                'currency' => 'usd',
                'unit_amount' => 2000,
                'product_data' => [
                    'name' => 'Stubborn Attachments',
                ],
            ],
            'quantity' => 1,
        ]],
        'mode' => 'payment',
        'success_url' => route('welcome'),
        'cancel_url' => route('welcome'),
    ]);
    echo json_encode(['id' => $checkout_session->id], JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
}
```

The route for the controller method is `Route::post('stripe', [StripeController::class, 'store'])->name('stripe-store');`

Please help.

Comment: can you share what part of the stripe docs you're trying to convert to Laravel? I feel like there's something that may have gone missing while attempting to write the PHP example to Laravel

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/integration-builder

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add your route url in `VerifyCsrfToken` .This will exclude validating csrf token .You can find this middleware in `App\Http\Middleware` path folder

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'stripe',
       
    ];
}
```

As official documentation says

> Sometimes you may wish to exclude a set of URIs from CSRF protection.
> For example, if you are using Stripe to process payments and are
> utilizing their webhook system, you will need to exclude your Stripe
> webhook handler route from CSRF protection since Stripe will not know
> what CSRF token to send to your routes. Typically, you should place
> these kinds of routes outside of the web middleware group that the
> App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider applies to all routes in the
> routes/web.php file. However, you may also exclude the routes by
> adding their URIs to the $except property of the VerifyCsrfToken
> middleware:

Ref for laravel 8:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf#preventing-csrf-requests

Ref for laravel 10 : https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris

Comment: Thanks. It solves the `419 (unknown status)` error.  Now I have _SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 75_ for `console.error("Error:", error);`  May be my controller method is not retruning json? any suggestion?

Comment: @Ahsan use `return response()->json([ 'id' =>$checkout_session->id]);` in your controller instead of the `echo`. That way you don't need to add the content type header either and you generate a correctly response object. This being said there's likely another error going on though so might want to check the actual response content to see what it says